# Read XML file from a web server

Tags: java

I need to know how I can read a xml file which is placed at web.war. This also needs to be server independent.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just read it using the usual suspects from java.io , and parse it using JAXP (Java API for XML Processing, it comes bundled with java since v. 1.4) .

JAXP is quite extensive and flexible, and provides quite a few different ways of accomplishing what you want. A straight forward way is to use the  DOM XML parser.

Look here for a example of how you use that

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

**UPDATED**

To answer the question in you comment, if you need the path to a file which lies somewhere within the context of the web application, look into ServletContext (more specifically, the getContextPath() method)

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I can read it using either sax parser or dom parser but the issue is to get the path irrespective of the web server. for ex. in jboss i need to put the xml under deploy folder where in tomcat i need to put it under webapps folder. how can i get the path to that file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SAX parser to read XML file .
Go through this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

will help you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I can read it using either sax parser or dom parser but the issue is to get the path irrespective of the web server. for ex. in jboss i need to put the xml under deploy folder where in tomcat i need to put it under webapps folder. how can i get the path to that file ?